# How can I simply add comments and to-do's with a symbol in the margin?

Tags: macros

I love latex but I'm tired of sending my comments to a document by mail, instead of writing them down in the document.

I'm looking for a **simple** (as simpler as posible) way to add a block of text, with the proper alignment, and indicate with a symbol in the right margin that it is:

- a **comment**
- a **to do** item
- something else I come up

Can I do that with a command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specify the Minimal Working Example (MWE). From this much text, nothing is clear.

Comment: the basic command would be `\marginpar{a comment here}` but there are several packages with fancier versions including a `todo` package.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for PDF annotations that can be made in directly a PDF viewer? Or do you want something like the [`todo`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todo) package "from within LaTeX"?

Comment: Yes, for commenting a text, you have to select the text and just press ctrl+t, similarly for the reverse you can go with ctrl+u after selecting the text. This is compatible with TexStudio editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **simpler** way I can think of is this:

```
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{{[{\textbf{Comment:}\textit{#1}]}}\marginpar{$\bigodot$}}  %a comment
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{[\textbf{To do:} #1]}\marginpar{$\bigotimes$}}  %things to do
\newcommand{\nameofyourcommand}[1]{{[{\textbf{Before the text:}\textit{#1}]}}\marginpar{symbolyouwant}}  %another command
```

Simply use it like:

```
\todo{Do this}
\mycomment{and remember that I told you ...}
```

with this result:

[image]